# IP address changed on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

The public IP address on my Debian server hosted on Google Compute Engine.  Have not touched configuration for it in the console in a while.  The new IP address is reflected in the Google Compute Engine Console.  How can I find out why this happened and prevent it from happening again.  I am not paying $100/mo for support, so they won't let me open a support ticket unless it is billing related.  I have never had this problem before with any of the other Google Compute Engines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should reserve a `global static ip` : https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address